# Google Sign In API for iOS Credentials for backend (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I have implemented Google Sign In in my iOS application and i want to send the ID Token of the user to my server for validation. I have created a Client ID for iOS through Google Cloud Platform Console and although i use the same client ID on my app and on my server, when i send the request to the server, the server throws a 500 error. Should i use another kind of Client ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    *

Error code 500 is an internal server error. so check issues using postman.

        @IBAction func GoogleLoginBtn(_ sender: Any) {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
            }

        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user:GIDGoogleUser!,withError error: Error!) {
               print(error)
                return
            }

            func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

                if (error == nil) {
                    // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
                    id = user.userID
                    Name = user.profile.name
                    Email = user.profile.email
                    url = String(describing: user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: (400))!)
        }
        }

    In-app delegate:-
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "76lp4.apps.googleusercontent.com"
// paste ur reverse client id here
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
            print("UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue: \(UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue)")
            print("UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue: \(UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue)")
                return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
                                                         sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?,
                                                         annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        }
```

*